# Problema con Windows y C

Tags: c, windows

hoy me decidí a aprender C, estoy creando un programa muy básico que saqué el promedio de 4 números que se le ingresen al programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int calif1, calif2, calif3, calif4, total;
    printf(" introduzca el valor de la primera nota: ");
    scanf("%i", calif1);
    printf("\n introduzca el valor de la segunda: ");
    scanf("%i",calif2);
    printf("\n introduzca el valor de la tercera: ");
    scanf("%i",calif3);
    printf("\n introduzca el valor de la cuarta: ");
    scanf("%i",calif4);
    total = calif1 + calif2 + calif3 + calif4;
    printf("el promedio es: %i",total/4);
}
```

despues de compilar con TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit (no se si esta información les sirva) me aparecio este mensaje de windows:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿que puedo hacer y a que se debe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer uso de scanf necesitas pasarle la referencia de la variable en caso de que esta no sea un puntero o un array, esto se logra a través del uso del ampersand (&).

```
scanf("%i", &calif1);
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int calif1, calif2, calif3, calif4, total = 0;
    printf(" introduzca el valor de la primera nota: ");
    scanf("%i", &calif1);
    printf("\n introduzca el valor de la segunda: ");
    scanf("%i", &calif2);
    printf("\n introduzca el valor de la tercera: ");
    scanf("%i", &calif3);
    printf("\n introduzca el valor de la cuarta: ");
    scanf("%i", &calif4);
    total = calif1 + calif2 + calif3 + calif4;
    printf("el promedio es: %i",total/4);

    return 0;
}
```